# Compute nth prime at compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, compile-time, constexpr

The C++11 features, with `constexpr` and template argument packs, should in my opinion be strong enough to perform some rather complex computations. One possible example for which I have a practical application is the computation of the nth prime at compile time.

**I'm asking for ways to implement this computation.** If more than one solution are proposed, it might be interesting to compare them.

To give you an idea of my performance expectations: I'd hope for some code which can find the 512th prime (which is 3671) in less than one second compile time on reasonable desktop hardware.

Comment: 512th prime can be easily found in less than 1 second using a normal sieve though.

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: If you need this at compile time, run a prime number generator as part of your build process. Or just put `3671` in by hand. It'll be much quicker.

Comment: Well, I have seen the 8 queens problems being solved at compile-time; so it certainly seems possible. However it's possibly tricky because we (C++ developers) are not used thinking the functional way.

Comment: Also see [History of TMP](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Templates/Template_Meta-Programming#History_of_TMP) for mention of Erwin Unruh's program which computed prime numbers as error messages.

Comment: templates are turing complete, so the problem is clearly solvable, but why bother?  @PeterWood's suggestion of running a prime number generator as part of your build process will result in a much cleaner solution: easier to understand and to maintain.  Although templates are turing complete, the results is _not_ particularly readable, and TMP should only be used when compiler internal information (like type information) is needed for the calculations.  Otherwise, an external generator should be preferred.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I implemented the simplest possible way, not using templates at all and it works:

```
constexpr bool isPrimeLoop(int i, int k) {
    return (k*k > i)?true:(i%k == 0)?false:isPrimeLoop(i, k + 1);
}

constexpr bool isPrime(int i) {
    return isPrimeLoop(i, 2);
}

constexpr int nextPrime(int k) {
    return isPrime(k)?k:nextPrime(k + 1);
}

constexpr int getPrimeLoop(int i, int k) {
// i - nr of primes to advance
// k - some starting prime
    return (i == 0)?k:getPrimeLoop(i - 1, nextPrime(k + 1));
}

constexpr int getPrime(int i) {
    return getPrimeLoop(i, 2);
}

static_assert(getPrime(511) == 3671, "computed incorrectly");
```

It needs increased constexpr-depth a bit, but it fits in time easily:

```
$ time g++ -c -std=c++11 vec.cpp -fconstexpr-depth=600

real    0m0.093s
user    0m0.080s
sys 0m0.008s
```

The following trick reduces depth of `getPrimeLoop` recursion to logarithmic, so g++ can complete with default depth (without measurable time penalty):

```
constexpr int getPrimeLoop(int i, int k) {
    return (i == 0)?k:
        (i % 2)?getPrimeLoop(i-1, nextPrime(k + 1)):
        getPrimeLoop(i/2, getPrimeLoop(i/2, k));
}
```

Comment: So the lesson to learn here seems to be: remembering the primes we already found has a far higher cost than it is worth. Interesting, I guess it makes sense in hindsight but it still feels kind of strange. Thanks for providing that approach!

Comment: Two extra words about scaling: binary recursion trick might be necessary in other parts of algorithm; `k*k` might cause integer overflow.

Comment: I take that back about the security guards. Applause!

Comment: Searching for a feature request to lift the constexpr-depth limit for tail recursion, I came about [this article](http://fendrich.se/blog/2012/11/22/compile-time-loops-in-c-plus-plus-11-with-trampolines-and-exponential-recursion/) which describes ways to keep the recursion depth low, very much like your binary recursion, and uses a primality check as running example.

Answer (score 5):

I doubt that your 1 second goal is within reach of any hardware that 
doesn't have security guards. However I believe the following 
meta-program can close down on it a lot:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<unsigned N>
using boolean = std::integral_constant<bool,N>;

template<unsigned N>
constexpr bool is_co_prime()
{
    return true;
};

template<unsigned N, unsigned D>
constexpr bool is_co_prime()
{
    return N % D != 0;
};

template<unsigned N, unsigned D0, unsigned D1, unsigned ...Di>
constexpr bool is_co_prime()
{
    typedef typename std::conditional<
        is_co_prime<N,D1>(),
        typename std::conditional<
            is_co_prime<N,Di...>(),
            boolean<is_co_prime<N,D0>()>,
            std::false_type
        >::type,
        std::false_type
    >::type type;
    return type::value;
};

template<unsigned N>
constexpr unsigned inc()
{
    return N == 2 ? 3 : N + 2;
}

template<unsigned Counter, unsigned Candidate, unsigned ...Primes>
struct nth_prime;

template<unsigned Candidate, unsigned Prime, unsigned ...Primes>
struct nth_prime<0,Candidate,Prime,Primes...>
{
    static const unsigned value = Prime;
};

template<unsigned Counter, unsigned Candidate = 2, unsigned ...Primes>
struct nth_prime
{
    typedef typename std::conditional<
        is_co_prime<Candidate,Primes...>(),
        nth_prime<Counter - 1,inc<Candidate>(),Candidate,Primes...>,
        nth_prime<Counter,inc<Candidate>(),Primes...>
    >::type type;
    static const unsigned value = type::value;
};

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << nth_prime<512>::value << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'll call this meta-program *MyNthPrime* and call your one *YourNthPrime*.

Your seem to have much heftier hardware than mine and certainly more memory. I 
have a routine Lenovo ThinkPad T420, 4-core i5, 8GB RAM, 8GB swap, running Linux
Mint 14, kernel 3.5.0. You report it takes you 3 mins. to build your *YourNthPrime*.
Measured by the `time` command, it takes me 35 mins. to build *YourNthPrime*,
with no apps running but the terminal and system monitor.

The compiler is GCC 4.7.2 and the commandline the options are:

```
-Wall -O0 -std=c++11 -ftemplate-depth=1200
```

That elapsed time breaks down as:

```
real    34m2.534s
user    3m40.414s
sys     0m33.450s
```

It takes me 1.5 mins to build *MyNthPrime*, with:

```
-Wall -O0 -std=c++11 -ftemplate-depth=2100
```

and the elapsed time breaks down as:

```
real    1m27.832s
user    1m22.205s
sys     0m2.612s
```

That `-ftemplate-depth=2100` is not a transposition typo. More of this
shortly.

*MyNthPrime* isn't fairly and squarely 23 times faster than *YourNthPrime*. The 
broken-down timings suggest that *MyNthPrime* is actually around
2.75 times as fast as as *YourNthPrime* on user-time. But they also show 
that *YourNthPrime*'s build really lost the farm on real time. What was it
doing for the fruitless 9/10ths of its existence?  Swapping, of course.

Both builds scoffed 95% of my 8GB system RAM within 45 secs., but *MyNthPrime*
topped out around there and didn't swap. *YourNthPrime* went on eating swap 
space up to a peak 3.9GB, and long before that all my CPUs were dozing.

This point is notable when you take it with the fact that *MyNthPrime* 
needs getting on for twice as much `-ftemplate-depth` as *YourNthPrime*. 
Folk wisdom is that an extravagant `-ftemplate-depth` is the road to 
ruin for a meta-program build time, because it equates to extravagant 
memory consumption, which only has to slide into heavy swapping and
you're watching paint dry. But the run-off of *YourNthPrime* and *MyNthPrime* does 
not bear this out - quite the opposite. The lesson I take is that
the *depth* to which you must instantiate recursive templates is not
always a good measure of the *quantity* of template instantiating you
must do, and it is the quantity that matters for your memory resources.

Although they don't look superficially similar, *MyNthPrime* and *YourNthPrime*,
both implement the trial-division algorithm for prime generation. *MyNthPrime*
is that much faster solely because it is rather more shrewdly coded to
be sparing to of recursive template instantiations, and of the memory they gobble up.

*YourNthPrime* fields 4 recursive templates for the computation, *all
consuming the same recursive variadic template argument list*. 
*MyNthPrime* fields 2: it's just giving the compiler about half as
many enormous instantiations to do.

*YourNthPrime* (as I read it) perceives the potential efficiency of 
doing its trial-divisions in ascending order of the primes in hand - because the chances of
successful division increase toward the smaller primes; and once a prime
in hand exceeds 1/2 of the candidate number being divided, the chances are 0.
Hit the most likely divisors first and you optimize your prospect of a quick
verdict and exit. But an obstacle to exploiting this efficiency is the fact that
the primes in hand are represented by a variadic template argument list with the *largest*
always at its head. To surmount this obstacle *YourNthPrime* deploys the recursive
variadic template function `lastArg<>()`, effectively to reverse the
order in which the primes in hand are consumed in the divisions.

`lastArg<>()` presents the primes in hand to the template
function:

```
template<unsigned i, unsigned head, unsigned... tail>
constexpr bool isPrime() {
    return i % head && isPrime<i, tail...>();
}
```

in ascending order for recursive trial division of the next candidate `i` 
by the primes `head, tail...`. It's here I think you look to `lastArg<>()`
to pay its way by ensuring `head` is always he next-best prospect for
getting you out of the costly righthand side of that `&&`.

But to achieve this `lastArg<>()` itself recursively traverses the whole
list of primes in hand at each invocation, before you even get the opportunity
for a verdict on `i`.  So it would be cheaper just to let `isPrime<>()` 
traverse the primes in hand as far as it needs to, testing `i` as it goes, 
dispense with `lastArg<>()` and save all the recursive instantiations
thereof.

The job done by `isPrime<>()` in *YourNthPrime* - the recursive trial division -
is done in *MyNthPrime* by:

```
template<unsigned N, unsigned D0, unsigned D1, unsigned ...Di>
constexpr bool is_co_prime()
{
    typedef typename std::conditional<
        is_co_prime<N,D1>(),
        typename std::conditional<
            is_co_prime<N,Di...>(),
            boolean<is_co_prime<N,D0>()>,
            std::false_type
        >::type,
        std::false_type
    >::type type;
    return type::value;
};
```

`is_co_prime<>()` takes 10 lines to do what `is_prime<>()` does in one,
I could have done it in one line also:

```
return is_co_prime<N,D0>() && is_co_prime<N,D1,Di...>();
```

could be the body of the function. But the ugly trounces the pretty for 
efficiency here. Every time `is_prime<>()` has to recurse into the tail,
that tail is only one prime shorter than it was before. Every time 
`is_co_prime<>()` has to do the same thing the tail is *two* primes 
shorter than it was before. Its tail recursions are shallower in the 
worst case than those of `is_prime<>()` and there can only half as many.

`is_co_prime<>()` divides the candidate number `N` by the righthand - the 
smallest and likeliest - of any pair of available divisors *first*, 
and returns no-prime on success; otherwise recurses to any divisors still
to the right of that pair and continues trial division of the next-but-one
until success or exhaustion. Only at exhaustion does it resort to 
trial division by the larger of the the original pair - the least
likely divisor of any it has tried. And likewise within each of
the intervening smaller recursions, the least likely divisor gets
tried last.

Though this algorithm can be seen to get speedily to the smaller and 
likelier divisors of `N`, an itch will persist to get straight
to the smallest of them first and try them in true descending likelihood,
as per `lastArg<>()`. We have to quell this itch with the recognition
that any way of "getting straight to the smallest", when it is at the
tail of the list, will be a meta-function that must itself recurse over 
the whole list before we even get started with trial divisions. 
The implementation of `is_co_prime<>()` gets us down the list 
"two steps at a time" doing the trial division as it does so.

True, sometimes it will unluckily "step over" the largest divisor of `N`
first time and then won't find it again until and unless it bottoms out
and recurses backwards up the list. But once `N` is big enough to make it
matter there will mostly be at least one smaller divisor further on
to the right and it would be really unlucky to miss all of them. So the 
risk of skipping the largest on the way down is no big deal. Remember 
too there aren't going to be *any*  divisors on the way down till we 
reach the `N/2` point. That means the worst-case waste of recursions by 
skipping the one-and-only divisor of some `N` on the way down is confined
to the tail of the list from that point.

You speculate that a Sieve of Erathosthenes meta-program might
compile faster, and you are right. As a prime generator, Sieve has better
theoretical complexity than Trial Division. An elegant template 
meta-program implementation by [Peter Simons](http://cryp.to/), is 
[here](http://cryp.to/prime-sieve/), dating from 2006 or before. (And 
as Peter Wood commented, a non-terminating Sieve of Erathosthenes 
meta-program broke the news that the C++ template system is Turing-complete.) 
With C++11 facilities Simons' meta-program can be much abbreviated but 
I don't think made much more efficient. Just it stands, Simons 
Sieve can generate at compiletime all the primes up to the 512th in 
under 9 secs. on my ThinkPad. It needs `-ftemplate-depth=4000` or 
thereabouts to do it, but only about 0.5GB of memory - an even more 
arresting counterexample to the folk wisdom that big template-depth == 
big memory usage.

So Erathosthenes' Sieve leaves Trial Division floundering in the dust. 
Sadly, for the purpose of your exercise, Sieve is no use. It's called 
the *sieve* because we have to input an integer upper limit `U` and it 
sieves out of the composite numbers between 2 and `U`, leaving the primes.
Thus to apply it for finding exactly the Nth prime = `Pn` and not 
possibly any other, you must anyhow compute `Pn` in some other way, 
give Sieve an upper limit of `Pn + 1` (or `Pn + 2`, for `Pn > 2`), then
throw away all the `Pi, 2 <= Pi < Pn`, that it returns to you, and keep
just the `Pn` that you had already computed. This is a no-op.

Several of the commenters make the point that the identity any Nth prime
you could possibly generate by compiletime meta-programming will be
known beforehand or calculable beforehand by much simpler and vastly
faster means. I can't disagree, but I support your general point that
with C++11 facilities, TMP takes a huge stride toward real-world utility
that is well worth exploring - the more so as whatever takes a minute
to compile right now will take a second within in a decade.

Meanwhile, without even leaving our uncannily sophisticated C++ compilers,
with TMP problems like this we can still experience the nature of programming
an early computer, with clock speed and memory in the K's, in a "language"
modelled tightly - but within arcane constraints! - on classical recursive
function theory. That's why you've really gotta love them!

Comment: Excellent answer! Full of research, explanation, ideas, references.

Answer (score 1):

I've given this a try myself, and written the following implementation:

```
template<unsigned... args> constexpr unsigned countArgs();
template<> constexpr unsigned countArgs() { return 0; }
template<unsigned head, unsigned... tail>
constexpr unsigned countArgs() { return 1 + countArgs<tail...>(); }

template<unsigned last>
constexpr unsigned lastArg() { return last; }
template<unsigned head, unsigned next, unsigned... tail>
constexpr unsigned lastArg() { return lastArg<next, tail...>(); }

template<unsigned i> constexpr bool isPrime() { return true; }
template<unsigned i, unsigned head, unsigned... tail>
constexpr bool isPrime()
{ return i % head && isPrime<i, tail...>(); }

template<bool found, unsigned i, unsigned... primesSoFar> struct nextPrime
{ static constexpr unsigned val =
    nextPrime<isPrime<i + 2, primesSoFar...>(), i + 2, primesSoFar...>::val; };
template<unsigned i, unsigned... primesSoFar> struct
nextPrime<true, i, primesSoFar...> { static constexpr unsigned val = i; };

template<unsigned n, unsigned... primesSoFar> struct nthPrimeImpl
{ static constexpr unsigned val = nthPrimeImpl<n - 1, primesSoFar...,
    nextPrime<false, lastArg<primesSoFar...>(), primesSoFar...>::val>::val; };
template<unsigned... primesSoFar> struct nthPrimeImpl<0, primesSoFar...>
{ static constexpr unsigned val = lastArg<primesSoFar...>(); };

template<unsigned n>
constexpr unsigned nthPrime() {
  return n == 1 ? 2 : nthPrimeImpl<n - 2, 3>::val;
}

constexpr unsigned p512 = nthPrime<512>();
static_assert(p512 == 3671, "computed incorrectly");
```

This requires increasing the maximum template depth of `gcc` to more than the default of 900 (in my gcc 4.7.2), e.g. by passing `-ftemplate-depth=1200`. And it is *way too slow*: it takes about 3 *minutes* on my hardware. So I very much hope for some more efficient code in a different answer.

In terms of computation method, the above does something like [trial division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division). A [sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) might perform better, but so far I couldn't think of a way to write that in a constexpr-compatible fashion.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer by Mike Kinghan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15454201/1468366) got me thinking along lines I hadn't though before. If template instantiation is such a problem which causes such severe memory consumption, how can we reduce that? I eventually came up with a scheme where instead of an argument pack for all primes found so far, I use a chain of types, each one referencing the one before, and a chain of static functions in these types which can use the ones from types before.

The result I'll paste below is still a lot slower than [the one suggested by zch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15455090/1468366), but I find it interesting enough to share, since it might be a useful approach for other applications.

```
template<unsigned N> struct NthPrime {
  typedef NthPrime<N - 1> previous;
  static constexpr unsigned prime = previous::nextPrime();
  static constexpr unsigned nextPrime() { return nextCoprime(prime + 2); }
  static constexpr unsigned nextCoprime(unsigned x) {
    // x is a candidate. We recurse to obtain a number which is
    // coprime to all smaller primes, then check that value against
    // the current prime.
    return checkCoprime(previous::nextCoprime(x));
  }
  static constexpr unsigned checkCoprime(unsigned x) {
    // if x is coprime to the current prime as well, then it is the
    // next prime. Otherwise we have to try the next candidate.
    return (x % prime) ? x : nextCoprime(x + 2);
  }
};

template<> struct NthPrime<1> {
  static constexpr unsigned prime = 2;
  static constexpr unsigned nextPrime() {
    return 3;
  }
  static constexpr unsigned nextCoprime(unsigned x) {
    return x; // x is guaranteed to be odd, so no need to check anything.
  }
};

template<unsigned n>
constexpr unsigned nthPrime() {
  return NthPrime<n>::prime;
}

constexpr unsigned p512 = nthPrime<512>();
static_assert(p512 == 3671, "computed incorrectly");
```

The beast above requires modifications both to the constexpr depth and the template depth. The following values are sharp bounds for my compiler.

```
time g++-4.7.2 -c -fconstexpr-depth=519 -ftemplate-depth=2042 -std=c++11 foo.cc

real    0m0.397s
user    0m0.368s
sys     0m0.025s
```