# C++: are "trait" and "meta-function" synonymous?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

Or, does *trait* perhaps refer to a specific way to utilizing *meta-functions*?

If they are **not** synonymous, please point me to some examples of *traits* which are not *meta-functions* or those of *meta-functions* which are not *traits*.  An actually working piece of code, perhaps within STL or Boost libraries, would be appreciated rather than a contrived toy example.

I'd like to see how experts in this field of C++ programming use these terminologies.  I'm not sure if there are authoritative definitions of them...

Thanks in advance!

---

Clarification: It's not that I looking for **any** examples of traits or meta-functions.  I've been using tens (if not hundreds) of them at my day job.

[image: Venn0110.svg]
"[Venn0110](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Venn0110.svg#/media/File:Venn0110.svg)". Licensed under Public Domain via [Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Meta" is C++ terminology for template programming. A clear example is the Boost Meta Programming Library (MPL).

In this sense, a meta-function is a function whose domain is not objects but C++ constructs. The common inputs are therefore types, ordinary functions and other templates.

A simple meta-function is for example `template<typename T> using Foo = Bar<T, int>` which has as its input a type `T` and as its output a type `Foo<T>`. Trivial, yes, but ordinary functions can be trivial too.

A trait is a metafunction whose codomain is a constant expression, often boolean. E.g. `is_foo<T>::value` obviously is boolean. The oldest trait in this sense is `sizeof(T)` whose codomain is `size_t`.

Comment: "A trait is a metafunction whose codomain is a constant expression" All right, I'll take this as your take-home message for me

Answer (score 4):

The terms are not equivalent.

### Meta functions

The term is not defined in the C++ Standard.

There seem to be two main contending definitions:

1) "meta-functions derive/calculate/map-to values or types (based on their arguments/parameters) ***at compile time***", *and/or*

- `constexpr` functions may or may not be included in any given person's definition/conception; there's functional overlap, but much existing writing mentioning meta functions predates or just doesn't also discuss `constexpr` functions, so it's hard to know whether any definition or examples given *deliberately* leaves room for or excludes them

2) "meta-functions are functions and/or classes utilising ***template meta-programming***", which specifically means a core of code (the template) may be reused for different parameters, performing some code generation or transformation based thereon

- it's not necessarily the case that a meta-programming's final product is a compile-time type or constant - it may be a function intended for use with runtime values or data

#### A small survey of top google results for "meta function c++"

["metafunctions accept types and compile-time constants as parameters and return types/constants. A metafunction, contrary to its name, is a class template."](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Metafunction)

["code...executed and its result used while...compiling. ...meta-functions can compute two things: values or types"](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2012/03/19/meta-functions-in-c11/)

[this article](http://cpptruths.blogspot.hk/2011/07/want-speed-use-constexpr-meta.html) uses "meta function" to refer to class templates yielding compile-time values/types

---

### Traits

The C++ Standard doesn't define "traits", but does define "traits class"es:

**17.3.25 [defns.traits] traits class**

> a class that encapsulates a set of types and functions necessary for class templates and function templates to manipulate objects of types for which they are instantiated
>   [ Note: Traits classes defined in Clauses 21, 22 and 27 are character traits, which provide the character handling support needed by the string and iostream classes. —end note ]

I'd add that traits can have *values*, as well as types and functions - for example [`rank`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/rank) exposes `::value`.  Traits provide types/values offering insight into either the parameter type itself, or the behaviour desired of the system using the trait when that system's working on variables of that type.

The Standard Library's character traits contain example of *runtime* functionality: for example `X::length(p)`, `X::find(p, n, c)`.

The [`<type_traits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) header in the C++ Standard Library is a good place to get an initial feel for what kind of things traits can be used for.

Traits are traditionally and typically (but now C++11 provides `constexpr` functions not necessarily) classes, as distinct from functions meta- or otherwise.

A trait might tell you if a parameter `T` is constant or not, whether it's serialisable, or whether it should be compressed when transmitted via TCP: whatever some other general-purpose code might need to customise its behaviour for the range of types it handles.

Sometimes traits will be provided by the system that uses them - other times they can be supplied by client code wishing to customise its behaviour on a per-type basis.

Traits may deduce things using various tests of the parameter types, or they may be hand-crafted specialisations hard-coding values for specific types.

This ACCU introduction to traits](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/442) is worth reading, and includes this quote from the creator of C++:

> Think of a trait as a small object whose main purpose is to carry information used by another object or algorithm to determine "policy" or "implementation details". - *Bjarne Stroustrup*

### Contrasting "meta function" with "traits"

Regardless of which definition of meta function you adopt, the criteria relates to implementation details: when the function can be evaluated, and/or whether it involves code generation/transformation.  That contrasts with traits, where the key concept/requirement is the purpose to which they're put, not the common - but far from universal - implementation using template specialisations or instantiations, or any capacity for compile time vs run-time evaluation.

Comment: "A *trait* ... provides different values depending on the parameter(s)"  Sounds almost like [definition of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Definition)!  You are arguing against your conclusion that "[t]he terms are not equivalent."

Comment: @nodakai: I'm not... a trait - being a template - can have *types* as parameters (as well as integral values), while a function's arguments can not include types.  The trait's members can typically be calculated at compile time too, which before C++11 `constexpr` wasn't possible with functions.

Comment: I referred to "function" in the mathematician's sense (see my link to Wikipedia,) not in the C++'s sense.  Another question... "The trait's members can typically be calculated at compile time too"  From your wording of "typically," I got an impression that there exists a trait whose member must be computed runtime.  Is this true, or did you simply have in mind the fact that optimizing compilers don't give any *guarantees* on how they optimize complex expressions?

Comment: @nodakai: re function in a mathematical sense vs C++ - feel free to adjust your reading of my previous statements accordingly.  The C++ Standard defines *traits class* in 17.3.25 [defns.traits] as *"class that encapsulates a set of types and functions necessary for class templates and function templates to manipulate objects of types for which they are instantiated"* - that's been more or less the same for at least 15 years, well before functions could be `constexpr`, so there's scope for "runtime" traits though the association of traits with compile time is strong in C++.

Comment: @nodakai: as a random example of the use of the term "traits" to refer to runtime processes, see Alexandrescu's [article here](https://erdani.com/publications/traits_on_steroids.html), e.g. `MtRefCountingTraits`, though more recently the term "policies" might have been used instead.

Answer (score 2):

A metafunction (in the context of C++) is a function that produces a result that can be used at compile time.   The result can either be types (which can only be obtained at compile time by definition, using techniques such as partial specialisation) or values (which can be computed at compile time, using the fact that template parameters can be integral values, not just types).

A trait is essentially a class (or object) that packages up information (policy contraints, type characteristics, implementation details) for use by another class (or object) at compile time.   The information packaged up can consist of type information (e.g. `typedef`s) or properties of interest.   For example, `std::numeric_limits<T>` (available through `<limits>`) is a "type trait" which provides information about arithmetic types (e.g. is `T` an integral type? is the set of values a `T` can represent bounded or finite? is `T` `signed`? etc).  The information is packaged in a form so that metaprograms (i.e. template functions or classes) can use the information at compile time.   For example, a template metafunction might use information from a type trait to ensure the template is only instantiated for unsigned integral types, and trigger a compilation error if an attempt is made to instantiate the template for other types.

In this sense, a trait is a type of metafunction that provides information at compile time for use by other metafunctions.

Comment: "a trait is a type of metafunction" This agrees with my vague understanding of them.

"... that provides information at compile time for use by other metafunctions." So you focused on their use cases.  Interesting.

By the way, "A metafunction (in the context of C++) is a function that produces a result that can be used at compile time."  But you won't call a [C++11 constexpr function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15289678/compute-nth-prime-at-compile-time) "metafunction"

Comment: I said nothing about `constexpr`, since you didn't ask about it.  But, yes, `constexpr` functions can be viewed as a type of metafunction.    Before C++11 (when `constexpr` was introduced), metafunction programming in C++ typically was concerned with techniques involving templates.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there aren't any formal definitions of these terms.  So I'll provide the ones that I use.

Metafunctions are templates which return a type.  Usually, the returned result is a type which contains a member type named "type" so it can be accessed via the suffix ::type. Example invoking a metafunction:

```
using new_type = std::common_type<int, char>::type;
```

(see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type)

A trait would be be special type of metafunction which returns a result convertible to bool. Example:

```
bool ic = std::is_convertible<char, int>::type;
```

Note that nowadays, the requirement that a metafunction result have a member name "type" is relaxed so some metafunctions might be defined in such a manner that the ::type can be dropped. Example:

```
bool ic = std::experimental::is_convertible_v<char, int>;
```