# Unique integer for every list of data types

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I am trying to make a function that will take in some data types (through variadic templates) and return a unique integer for each combination of data types. It should return the same integer no matter the order of the data types; for instance, `GetNumber<int, double>()` should return the same integer as `GetNumber<double, int>()`. The purpose for this is to index from an array/lookup in an unordered map which will store a `MyClass<DataTypes>` at that position. Essentially, I am trying to get the corresponding object for any given combination of data types.

Thank you for taking the time to read this, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Why do you want this? What will this be used for? There may be a better way.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Really just a hash function. I'll be using the integer returned by `GetNumber` to index from a vector/lookup in a map. Each element in the vector/map will be MyClass<Ts>, and I need a quick way of finding an object given Ts. Hope that makes sense

Comment: I would edit the question to describe this in detail. It is likely that a static variable is not what you want.

Comment: Alright, good to know. I'll edit it.

Comment: What are you expecting when `GetNumber<int, int>()` returns? Is `GetNumber<int, int, int>()` an allowed combination?

Comment: @robthebloke The same data type shouldn't be repeated.

Comment: Why not just use type_index?

Comment: @n.m. That would give me a unique value for each individual type, but how would I use it to get a unique value for a _list_ of types?

Comment: `std::set<type_index>` can be used as a key in `std::map`. `std::vector<type_index>` too, but you will have to sort it and throw away duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as they don't have to be consecutive, you can construct unique identifiers for type lists by using the fact that integers have unique decompositions into primes.

Using the functions from [Generating prime numbers at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66239693/430766), we can assign unique prime numbers to every individual type ...

```
std::size_t typeIdGen() {
    static std::size_t n = 0;
    return n++;
}
template <typename>
std::uint64_t typePrime() { // assigns a unique prime for each distinct type
    static std::uint64_t const p = primeAtIndex(typeIdGen());
    return p;
}
```

... and then simply multiply them for the variadic type list:

```
template <typename... Ts>
std::uint64_t uniqueId() {
    return (typePrime<Ts>() * ... * 1);
}
```

Check out the [demo on compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/31dMvGcKo).

```
  std::cout << "(none): " << uniqueId<>() << '\n';
  std::cout << "int, float: " << uniqueId<int,float>() << '\n';
  std::cout << "float, int: " << uniqueId<float,int>() << '\n';
  std::cout << "double, bool, void*: " << uniqueId<double,bool,void*>() << '\n';
  std::cout << "int: " << uniqueId<int>() << '\n';
```

outputs:

```
(none): 1
int, float: 6
float, int: 6
double, bool, void*: 385
int: 2
```

Comment: Note: In C++23 all these functions could be consteval, but not in C++20 because of the static variable.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a very clever and efficient way of solving the problem!

Comment: @fat There was a mistake in the isPrime function, FYI. Also, if you are sure that no type can repeat in the argument list, you don't need primes. You can just flip the corresponding bit in the uint64_t result (the `typeId<T>()`th bit). This will keep the numbers a bit smaller and is computationally cheaper.

Comment: @Jarod42 Good point. I also removed `typeId` altogether.

Comment: That occurred to me last night right before I fell asleep, haha. I am a bit afraid that I'll end up with more than 64 data types, but that's probably unlikely.

Comment: @fat In that case, use `std::bitset` instead of `std::uint64_t`.

Comment: Note: order of instantiation might change with different run/build. In above example `int:2`/`float:3` is not guaranty, might be the opposite